# c++ requires expression with inverse return type concept check

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts, requires-expression

I try to define a concept with a requires expression which checks some member function existence on the type.
The problem I run into is, that a single concept has to be plugged in for the return type check without any preceding bool operations like "not". This forces me to also write concepts for the inverse if needed, which is not really handy.
Is there something I am missing or another good way to do it?

Simple example:

```
template <typename T>
concept IsReference = std::is_reference_v<T>;

template <typename T>
concept HasSomeFunction = requires (T t) {
    {t.func()} -> IsReference; /* this is ok */
    {t.anotherFunc()} -> (not IsReference); /* this is not ok */
};
```

Comment: So… you’re OK with `void`, `volatile void*`, `wchar_t(*(*(*)[])(...))[1]`, `float std::vector<bool>::*`, `std::in_place_type_t<void() volatile &&>`, `std::pair<int&,char&>`, and `std::reference_wrapper<int>`, but not `const int&`?  It seems questionable to have a syntax for “anything but this”.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a syntax that works on latest gcc and clang.

```
template <typename T>
concept HasSomeFunction = requires (T t) {
    {t.func()} -> IsReference; /* this is ok */
    requires !IsReference<decltype(t.anotherFunc())>;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5zr41dYhv)

It a bit harder to read. Maybe someone with some more experience with concepts can provide a better solution.

Comment: As far as my understanding goes - this is exactly the transformation the compiler is doing with the normal return type check - for me its unclear why the inverse would not be allowed with the shorter syntax

Comment: Yes, seems reasonable that it would work with the shorter version as well. I have no answer as to why it's not allowed.

Comment: @Lessi - Why just the inverse? Why not arbitrary boolean expression? The standard typically **avoids** special cases in grammar whenever it can. It won't allow *just* the inverse. And more than that is a can of worms.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica You are right - i was tight up with my specific example - conjunctions and disjunctions should also be possible.

Comment: @Lessi - Which won't fly. Since recommended practice in this case is to write a helper concept. Which leaves us with a can a worms that isn't even inline with common guidelines. So nobody will try to add it on a whim. If you disagree strongly, you can always write a proposal for C++23.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The question that comes to my mind is: Why would someone that writes a guideline prefer helper concepts over a simple boolean expression. From my perspective the boolean expression version would be much more readable and moreover in the same place with the usage, such that there is no potential need to jump to the definition of a helper.

Comment: @Lessi - Because a conjunction of conditions **is** a concept.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Exactly. So why is it not allowed in a return type check if thats the definition.

Comment: @Lessi - Write a proposal. Address comments and concerns from committee members, and go from there. Good luck.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In what case would that make a difference? Isn't a function call already an expression?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

struct B {};
struct D : B {};

template <typename T>
concept IsReference = std::is_reference_v<T>;
template <typename T>
concept NotIsReference = !std::is_reference_v<T>;

template <typename T>
concept HasSomeFunction = requires (T t) {
    {t.func()} -> IsReference; 
    {t.anotherFunc()} -> NotIsReference; 
};


int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::make_shared<D>();
    auto d = static_pointer_cast<D>(b);
    assert(d);
}
```

Comment: i think OP is asking how to avoid writing a `NotIsReference`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number exactly

Comment: btw comments are liars. `/* this is not ok */`, is it not ok?